# Flow does not catch AbortFLowException

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Juul Kable for Bluetooth low energy connection. when scanning for bluetooth devices i get a AbortFLowException in `Flow.first()` function when finding the element. for some reasons neither `flow.catch` nor a surrounding try catch can catch the exception.

```
scope.launch {
    try {
        var timeout = withTimeoutOrNull(SCAN_DURATION_MILLIS) {
            val advertisement = Scanner().advertisements
                .onCompletion { cause ->
                    if (cause != null) {
                        _scanStatus.value = ScanStatus.Stopped
                    }
                }.catch { cause ->
                    cause.printStackTrace()
                    _scanStatus.value = ScanStatus.Failed(cause.message ?: "Unknown error")
                }
                .first {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Device found in first: ${(it.name ?: "Name empty")}")
                    it.isSmartCap
                }

            callback(advertisement)
        }

        if (timeout == null) {
            _scanStatus.value = ScanStatus.Failed("Timeout")
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        _scanStatus.value = ScanStatus.Failed(e.message ?: "Unknown error")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a [bug in Kable](https://github.com/JuulLabs/kable/issues/67) that has been fixed in version `0.3.0`.